# Cheated his parents vs cheated on his parents

Tags: prepositions

> He **cheated on** his parents and made them sign the property papers.

Vs

> He **cheated** his parents and made them sign the property papers.

What preposition follows cheated in this case? 
Which is grammatically correct?

Comment: What do you actually want to say? Neither of these makes much sense to me. Please give us some context, else we can't tell you which is "correct".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the meaning you intend, use the second one.

> He cheated his parents and made them sign the property papers.

[*cheated on*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cheat-on) has a different meaning, for example "cheating on your spouse" or "cheating on a test".
It can't be applied to your context.

Comment: *He "fooled" / "bamboozled" / "tricked" / "deceived"  his parents **into** signing the property papers*. Would all be preferable than "cheated" and "made them".